# Memory errors/leaks when deleting a node in a self balancing binary search tree - how do I free its memory?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, binary-search-tree, avl-tree, tree-balancing

I am getting memory leaks specifcally when I am trying to a delete a node (as in when there are only insertion operations, there are no leaks) from my self balancing tree. After my delete and insertion operations are done, I call a function to destroy the tree, but there are still memory leaks. The function itself seems to be working fine (I print a pre order traversal of the tree after, and it is correct).
This is what my delete function looks like:

```
node * Delete(node *T,int x)
{
    node *p;
    
    if(T==NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
        if(x > T->data)     // insert in right subtree
        {
            T->right=Delete(T->right,x);
            if(BF(T)==2)
                if(BF(T->left)>=0)
                    T=LL(T);
                else
                    T=LR(T);
        }
        else
            if(x<T->data)
            {
                T->left=Delete(T->left,x);
                if(BF(T)==-2)   //Rebalance during windup
                    if(BF(T->right)<=0)
                        T=RR(T);
                    else
                        T=RL(T);
            }
            else
            {
                //data to be deleted is found
                if(T->right!=NULL)
                {   //delete its inorder succesor
                    p=T->right;
                    
                    while(p->left!= NULL)
                        p=p->left;
                    
                    T->data=p->data;
                    T->right=Delete(T->right,p->data);
                    
                    if(BF(T)==2)//Rebalance during windup
                        if(BF(T->left)>=0)
                            T=LL(T);
                        else
                            T=LR(T);\
                }
                else
                    return(T->left);
            }
    T->ht=height(T);
    return(T);
}
```

And my destroy/ free function:

```
void destroytree (node* root)
{
  if (root == NULL)
  {
     return;
  }
  destroytree(root->left);
  destroytree(root->right);
  printf("%d\n",root->key); // just to see what is happening.
  free(root)
  return;
}
```

I don't know how to free up the memory of the node that I am deleting. That is why there are memory leaks - when I print the root that is being freed(in destroytree), it is always the deleted node that is missing, therefore I think that's where memory leak is. My only problem is , with the deletenode function I've written I don't know where to free up this memory. I would appreciate any help. Also, I malloc in my insert node ofcourse, when I am inserting the node.

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and learn to use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), and the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/). Draw on some board your intuition about the [heap](https://gribblelab.org/CBootCamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html) with arrows representing pointers

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thank you but I just used valgrind to find the memory leak, like I said I know where it is coming from ( as I mentioned in the post) I just need help to free it while keeping the functionality of my function.

Comment: StackOverflow is *not* a do-my-homework website. You should provide some [mre] in your question, and take inspiration from *existing* code on [github](http://github.com/) or [gitlab](http://gitlab.com/). Read also [*Introduction to Algorithms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) and wikipage on [AVL trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) or [red-black trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)